# NavigationLink open destination without isActive enabled

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui, swiftui-ontapgesture

I have a `NavigationLink` with a simple text. Should open a secret logged-in page if determinated conditions are verified.

But I noticed that I can bypass the "`isActive`" with two simple tricks:

1. **long press** on text **and release**, Secret view automatically loads
2. **press and drag** the text, Secret view automatically loads

So I decided to implement and catch the `longPress`.
Implementing it, I solved the problem number 1, but the seconds still exist.

Here a video that explain better this issue: https://youtu.be/vuaT3lwUhLg

Here the simple snippet recorded in the video:

```
// the secret logged page
struct LoggedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("secret view")
    }
}

// the example
struct ContentView: View {

    // loginSuccess is FALSE, so LoggedView() should not be called...
    @State var loginSuccess: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: LoggedView(), isActive: $loginSuccess) {
                
                Text("LOGIN")
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture(perform: {
                        // false, disabled to show the issue
                        loginSuccess = false
                    })
                    // if not implemented, longpress load the secret view
                    .onLongPressGesture {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

What's wrong with it?
`loginSuccess` is never true, why this is ignored?

Is a wrong implementation (as I suppose) or is a swift bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you just wanted to activate navigation programmatically, so you need active element like button or tappable view and hidden link.

Here is possible solution for your code

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
            
        Text("LOGIN")                   // << activator !!
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture(perform: {
                // false, disabled to show the issue
                loginSuccess = false
            })
            .background(
               NavigationLink(destination: LoggedView(), isActive: $loginSuccess) {
                 EmptyView()      // << hidden !!
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong with it?

You may be mistaking the role of `isActive`. It is not for enabling/disabling the link. It is intended to hold the state whether the destination View is currently active or not.

Why don't you simply use `disabled(_:)`?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var loggedViewActive: Bool = false
    // loginSuccess is FALSE, so LoggedView() should not be called...
    @State var loginSuccess: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: LoggedView(), isActive: $loggedViewActive) {
                
                Text("LOGIN")
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding()
            }
            .disabled(!loginSuccess)
        }
    }
}
```